# Querying an entity's HashMap

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm having problems on querying some entity that matches some criteria (key/value - coming from the web) with it's HashMap.

The entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
class Entity {
   @ElementCollection
   @MapKeyColumn(name = "context_key")
   @Column(name = "context_value")
   @CollectionTable(name = "entity_context_data", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id"))
   private Map<String, String> contextData = new HashMap<>();
}
```

I'm trying to query the Entity using Criteria:

```
 Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Entity.class, "entity")

for (Entry<String, String> entry : keyValuesFromWeb.entrySet()) {
   criteria.add(in(entry.getKey(), Arrays.asList(entry.getValue())));
}
```

But this clearly doesn't work. According to https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6103 it should be solved. 
Anybody who got this working?

Comment: Why dont' u first create ur list collection, and then add a single Restriction, instead of adding it in loop?

Comment: That doesn't work either...